# c# copy from text file to word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, text-files, winforms-interop

I want to copy data from text file to word file. I already have tried it with different alternatives like `string array`, `StringBuilder` and `StreamReader` using `Interop` which works good, but it takes too much time. It would really be thankful if anyone can suggest me with a better one. Been through many forms on the web, but couldn't find.

**FYI: My text file contains more than 1,00,000 lines.**

This is one of which I have tried:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path); //path is text file path
var doc = new MSWord.Document();

foreach (string lin in lines)
{
    doc.Content.Text += lin.ToString();
}

doc.Save();
```

Well, this works good but takes a lot of time and also sometimes throws an error like:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Word has encountered a problem.

Comment: Why not [File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_ReadAllText_System_String_) and then remove the `foreach` loop? That is much "cheaper" than concatenating strings in a loop. `doc.Content.Text = File.ReadAllText(path);`

Comment: Have you investigated what is causing the exception? For example - are there unusual characters in the string you are trying to append? Igor's solution would save time - but if the exception is due to the contents of your text file - then it may still happen.

Comment: @lgor: Yup that would actually do better, but it still takes more than 15 minutes of my time.

Comment: @PaulF: Yup I'm trying to find what exactly is causing the exception.  the thing is when I reduce the line items to few 1000's say 70k lines, it works good. But when again I increment to original line counts, it throws the error while saving the file.

Comment: @yusufhayırsever: I'm copying data from text file to word file.

Comment: @lgor: The reason I used a `foreach` loop is, I was getting error while using: `doc.Content.Text = File.ReadAllText(path);`

Comment: I'd suggest to try [Range.ImportFragment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.importfragment?view=word-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Word_Range_ImportFragment_System_String_System_Boolean_).

Comment: Instead of reading the file in using the File methods - can you open the text file with the MSWord document & then saving as word document.

Comment: @Filburt: `Range.ImportFragment()` is good. Thanks for that. But still I don't understand why I'm unable to write huge data into the word file!!!

Comment: @PaulF: Yup i thought of it but no luck. Can you suggest me anything on that?

Comment: @AshishSrivastava I'd suspect that there is a lot of overhead adding single lines whereas `ImportFragment` is likely optimized to use a Stream of some sort.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava: I have tried opening a small text file with Interop.Word & then using the SaveAs2 method changing the file extension & setting the format to WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument & that works correctly - I haven't got a big text file to see if there is a problem relating to size.

Comment: @PaulF: I will try that and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
        Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add();
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        System.Console.WriteLine("Starting");
        string path = @"C:\";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path + "\\big.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
        {
            wordDoc.Content.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            wordDoc.SaveAs("big.docx");
        }
        sw.Stop();
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Complete Time :{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Output :

```
Starting
Complete Time :5556
```

Or You can use Parallel :

```
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(sr.ReadToEnd(), i=>
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(i);
        });
        wordDoc.Content.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
        wordDoc.SaveAs(path + "\\big3.docx");
    }
```

Output:

```
Starting
Complete Time :2587
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be writing to a Word document, which is the specific query for the OP.

Comment: @OMANSAK: I'm copying data from text file to word file.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava fixed

Comment: @AshishSrivastava maybe u can use pararllel for more speed

Comment: String builder is not thread safe and even if it was using parallel would write to it unordered.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Word can read text files - so why not read the text file into an Interop Word Document & then convert by using one of the SaveAs methods.

I tested with a 34Mb, 1000000 line text file - the result was a 22Mb DOCX file:

```
MSWord.Application appAC = new MSWord.Application();
MSWord.Document doc = appAC.Documents.Open("TestRead.txt");
doc.SaveAs2(FileName:"TestSave", FileFormat:WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault);
doc.Close();
appAC.Quit();
```

Note that Microsoft states a maximum document size of 32MB - the text file exceeded this, but the resulting DOCX file was smaller - your exception maybe related to the size of the final file.